# InputStreamReader not able to connect to google places api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I am new to android development.

I am trying to build an app that shows my current location aswell as some places nearby, like a cafe.

I am working with eclipse using Google map api v2 and google place api.

I got my own api key for the android app and also for the server api and for the web as well.

I enabled the place at the google console.

At the moment what I am trying to do is to get the Json file back from google, and to print it out, the problem occur when I try to get the `InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());`

While running, in debug log, it shows me a screen in Eclipse that say that "source not found". Then the application stops.

I also looked out for questions and different tutorials but nothing works.

```
try{
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
         sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
         sb.append("&radius=5000");
         sb.append("&types=park");
         sb.append("&sensor=true");
         sb.append("&key=AIzaSyCzoxcu76TtGU9IS30x3fBKxi4GYAwrXRA");
                         URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
                          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                         //URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                  connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    String line;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));


            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             builder.append(line);
         }
                System.out.println("JSON BUILDER INPUT FROM GOOGLE PLACES QUERY="+builder.toString());
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: did you check that you have longitude and latitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove sensor parameter and try again, if problem still exists please provide logcat output.

Comment: it works... just tried https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40,40&radius=5000&types=park&key=AIzaSyCzoxcu76TtGU9IS30x3fBKxi4GYAwrXRA

Comment: thank you guys,
when i run it as a simple java project it works fine, but as android projct it does not!
what am i doing wrong??????

Comment: Have you set internet permission in manifest file?. Meanwhile if my answer solved your problem please mark it :)

Comment: because i cant uplod photo and i got anly 600 characters i will continue this post in another one.
I do have all the premissions.
i got the google-play-services_lib set as Lib, and its imported to the project.
I also tried to add a java class the the android project for it to get the connection and the Json file, but it didnt work.

Comment: <permission
        android:name="com.raz.testmap.premission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.raz.testmap.premission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.premission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

Comment: !-- The following two permissions are not required to use
      Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 
 <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

Comment: do i miss something??
also i dont realy know about the logcat output, while the app runs there is alot f data running in the logcat... what part shold i copy??